# AttributeError: module 'vertica_sdk' has no attribute 'UDSource'

Tags: python, vertica

I try to write a parser for vertica in python.
But i get this error message.

```
class MyParser(vertica_sdk.UDSource):
    def __init__(self):
            pass
    def setup(srvInterface, returnType):
            pass
    def process(self, srvInterface, inputbuffer, inputstate, streamwriter):
            print("1")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a vertica_sdk.UDParser - like here?
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/PythonSDK/UDParser.html

Comment: And what you posted does not look like an error message, but a code snippet ...